# YQL robots.txt restricted URL issues

Tags: sinatra, yql, robots.txt

I'm developing a webapp that includes the following YQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM html WHERE url="{URL}" and xpath="*"
```

I deployed a new version last week, and noticed that the page was hanging on the YQL query. When I came back yesterday, the problem seemed to have fixed itself over the weekend. I just deployed a new version to the server and the problem has come back again.  The server stack is Ngnix / Passenger / Sinatra

Punching the query into YQL Console I get an error:
"Requesting a robots.txt restricted URL:"

I've added the following robots.txt:

```
User-agent: Yahoo Pipes 2.0
Allow: /
```

But that doesn't seem to do anything.

Thoughts? It's pretty curious to me why YQL is reporting the URL is robots.txt restricted when it's not.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem. I have a suspicion that this is in part a problem on Yahoo's end.

In my Sinatra apps I added...

`get 'robots.txt' do

   "User-agent: * Allow: /"

end`

This would work occasionally... and then access would be denied again for a period of time.

If you are using this to avoid cross-domain issues with javascript... I eventually gave in and used a local PHP script to retrieve data rather than use YQL.

Answer (score 0):

Consider added *&diagnostics=true* in the YQL query. It worked for me.